# What may happen if sem_destroy() is not invoked on a semaphore in C?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, semaphore

This is regarding to semaphore programming in C language.

```html
    sem_t mutex;
    .
    .
    int main()
    {
        sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
        .
        .
        .
        .
        sem_destroy(&mutex);
        return 0;
    }
```

If I do not use sem_destroy() at the last of my programs, what implications it may cause?

Comment: I have heard that it can causes memory leaks, will find out more and answer it.

Comment: Given that you mentioned `sem_destroy`, are we talking about programs written in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is operating system specific. On Linux, read [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html); actually you are in an unspecified case. However, the documentation says

> Before being used, an unnamed semaphore must be initialized
>                 using sem_init(3).  It can then be operated on using
>                 sem_post(3) and sem_wait(3).  When the semaphore is no longer
>                 required, and before the memory in which it is located is
>                 deallocated, the semaphore should be destroyed using
>                 sem_destroy(3).

so **you should call `sem_destroy`** when appropriate; don't risk having a system-wide resource leak. BTW  documentation of [sem_destroy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_destroy.3.html) tells:

> An unnamed semaphore should be destroyed with sem_destroy() before
>       the memory in which it is located is deallocated.  Failure to do this
>       can result in resource leaks on some implementations.

For *named* semaphores, things are different (they sit in `/dev/shm/`). I guess that a *thread-shared* semaphore might be destroyed when its memory segment is removed (no more mapped by any process). I am not sure of this and it is implementation specific behavior, so don't rely on this.

Use also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

So what *may* happen is a *system-wide* [resource leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leak) and you don't want it. You might need to reboot to remove it. BTW, you could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out the actual syscalls involved, and you could look into the source code of your GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (or some other libc, like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) - and perhaps of the Linux kernel- to understand more the implementation specific behavior.

**Avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.

Comment: Ok so you mean the resources that has been allocated to the program would not be unallocated unless I destroy the semaphores?

Comment: Yes that *may* happen (or maybe not!). The exact behavior is undefined and is implementation specific.

Answer (score 1):

The address where Semaphore is stored will hold the last value of the semaphore if you dont use sem_destroy ...

It might cause problems as the semaphore's previous value might be indicating that a process is still running even if it is not  !

Comment: what problem, that's the question.